# Using exec and dynamic SQL to alter / repoint views with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Periodically I have to copy databases and update a set of around 50 views that point to a related database. I have a snippet of SQL that I can use to generate the alter view statements, which is this:

```
SELECT
  REPLACE (REPLACE (sm.definition, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW'), 
  'old_db_name.', 'new_db_name.') + '
  GO'
FROM
  sys.sql_modules sm
  JOIN
  sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
  WHERE
  sm.definition LIKE '%old_db_name.%' AND o.type = 'V'
```

This SQL runs and returns a set of SQL statements that I can cut and paste to a second query window to update the views. However, doing this for 50 views is tedious, so I would like to wrap this with some code to automatically run these updates. I have made an attempt, but for some reason it fails. Here is my code:

```
declare @view_replace table (sql varchar(8000)) 
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)

INSERT INTO @view_replace (sql)
SELECT
  REPLACE (REPLACE (sm.definition, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW'),    
  'old_db_name.', 'new_db_name.') + '
  GO'
FROM
  sys.sql_modules sm
  JOIN
  sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
  sm.definition LIKE '%old_db_name.%' AND o.type = 'V'

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT sql FROM @view_replace
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c
INTO @sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
exec (@sql)
FETCH NEXT FROM c
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

This runs without errors, and I see what looks like the 51 alter view statements running, but nothing has changed in the database! The views are still pointing to the old db. What have I got wrong? As a follow on, is this the most efficient way to script this sort of change? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgot something in loop

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    exec (@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c-->>>>>  into @sql
END
```

so only first statement executed